# AWS Cognito Identity Service Provider appears to store access token in local storage

Tags: angular, local-storage, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

We are developing an application that uses a Angular front end website. We are using AWS Appsync API for backend which requires amplify login

It works OK, but we have noticed that the Cognito provider stores the Cognito Details and access token in the browser local storage. This is what we see using F12 in Chrome and inspecting local storage. How to remove this localstorage or is there any way to encrypt that.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use a custom storage to store it where you believe it's best or in a secured way (react-secure-storage ?)

https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/manage-user-session/

```
class MyCustomStorage implements KeyValueStorageInterface {
    storageObject: Record<string, string> = {};   
    
    async setItem(key: string, value: string): Promise<void> {
        this.storageObject[key] = value;   
    }   
    async getItem(key: string): Promise<string | null> {
        return this.storageObject[key];   
    }   
    async removeItem(key: string): Promise<void> {
        delete this.storageObject[key];   
    }   
    async clear(): Promise<void> {
        this.storageObject = {};   
    } 
}

Amplify.configure({   Auth: authConfig });
    
cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.setKeyValueStorage(new MyCustomStorage());
```